# What does "left for dead" mean?

Tags: meaning, phrases

I'm not a native speaker. Also, I play video games. :P When the video game *Left 4 Dead* came out I thought the phrase was just a cool but largely meaningless title that hinted at the game being about zombies.

I, since then, found out it was a real phrase, but I'm still unsure as to what it really means. For example, the phrase "They were left for dead", does it mean something like this...

- "They were left to die [because there was no hope for them]", or maybe...
- "It was assumed they were dead by then." (ie. highly unlikely that they were still alive), or...
- "They were left there on purpose so they would die."

Also, another form of the phrase is "let die", which I first heard in Green Day's song "21 Guns":

> *When it's time to live and let die,*
>   *And you can't get another try,*
>   *Something inside this heart has died,*
>   *You're in ruins.*

Here it sounds more like it has a similar meaning to "give up [on life?]".

Could someone explain this phrase and its various forms to me?

Comment: The lyrics on *21 Guns* don't really have much to do with the expression *left for dead*. *Live and let die* is a sardonic twisting of the expression *Live and let live*, which basically means *Live your own life as you choose, so long as you allow others that same freedom"*.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

To understand what this simple phrase means first think of the literal meaning, that the person was abandoned because it was assumed that they were *already dead, mortally wounded or that it was inevitable that they die*.

But there is more to the phrase than that.  In common usage, this phrase is often part of a narrative where a person was expected to die, yet against the odds they survived.  Some examples from COCA:

> Left for dead by a busy road, Susan managed to get a ride to a police station where she insisted she be brought to the Nairobi Women's Hospital.
>
> Pueschel, just 11-years-old, was beaten, stabbed and left for dead, but he lived to testify against Reginald and Gerry Mahaffe.
>
> ... a young man in Los Angeles was robbed, shot, left for dead, but he lived because a bullet was stopped by a radio in his pocket.

The common theme in these stories is an act of cruelty towards an innocent person who survives either by a stroke of luck or a miracle.  A proper reading of the title *Left for Dead* should include cruelty, abandonment but also a sense of hope.

Answer (score 11):

Literally means to leave behind to die; to abandon someone as being dead. (The abandoned person may actually be alive.)

In general use, it means to abandon something because there is no hope for it.

Comment: I'm not sure that I've ever seen the phrase used in a metaphorical sense. In all cases I can think of, it's been used to literally refer to persons abandoned for dead. (I do have both editions of the videogame, by the way, which is quite good.)

Comment: Here's an example from a National Geographic article: https://bitly.com/p9BM27 (should be highlighted)

Comment: I voted for this but I'd go further than *may actually be*.  The person left for dead is *usually* alive, according to a quick survey of COCA hits for this phrase.

Comment: @The Raven: So you don't consider *left for dead* in the context of videogames to be "metaphorical"? You really *do* get immersed in your gaming!

Comment: @z7sg Ѫ: Surely the hits you find will be massively influenced by the fact that the abandonee *did in fact survive*, and lived to tell the tale. In most cases, whether they were already dead when abandoned, or died shortly afterwards, would be pure conjecture otherwise. Which would also stack the figures in favour of your interpretation, since we *like* to think they were still alive at the time. That's just part of myth-building, not real life.

Comment: I always assumed that someone left for dead was still alive at the time of being left (the reason doesn't matter), but with little chance of surviving.

Answer (score 5):

It means to me that they were left behind because everyone assumed they were dead or as good as dead.

Comment: I disagree.  The person may not be assumed dead, but there may be little or no hope for them.  There's a difference between "assumed dead" and "will likely die".

Comment: @Charles Goodwin: In principle you are right, but in practice one of the reasons for using the expression is that *from the point of view of those leaving* that difference is in fact irrelevant. Although obviously if you're saying it *from the viewpoint of those left*, it must mean you're still alive. Third parties will see things according to their moral position, not medical prognoses. It's not the exact words, it's the context/viewpoint which fixes the meaning.

Comment: I can't bring myself to agree with you.  The phrase "assumed dead" removes the dilemma involved when leaving people behind who are still living that, if accommodated, impact the survival chances of the group.

Comment: @Fumble I don't understand your comment *from the point of view of someone leaving* as I think there is a world of difference between leaving behind someone who you think is already dead and leaving someone who is likely to die.

Comment: @Charles Goodwin: I don't think *left for dead* is normally used in the context you outline (reluctantly, for the benefit of those who must push on unencumbered by the wounded). It's difficult to find a non-condematory expression for that one, obviously - probably just "left behind" is the best one can do.

Comment: @z7sg Ѫ: Movies excepted, those who are *left for dead* almost always *do* die. And the normal context is one where those who are leaving don't necessarily know (maybe don't even care) whether the abandonees are approaching, at, or just past the point of clinical death.

Comment: @Fumble It's funny but if you search for this phrase on COCA, most of the people left for dead seem to pull through in the end!  That's the principle use of this phrase anyway, regardless of whatever happens in reality to those who are abandoned.

Answer (score 1):

Colloquially it also means to beat somebody in a race so comprehensively that they might as well have been dead

Comment: Probably a better way of putting this, in the context of a race, is that it means to get away so quickly at the start that the subject might as well not have participated in the race, as opposed to might as well be dead.

Answer (score 1):

All three of OP's suggested interpretations of *left for dead* may be valid, according to context, although the third would more likely be phrased as *left to die*. In the real world I think it makes little difference which meaning one assumes.

@Martin Beckett correctly points up another, rather different, colloquial usage.

Per my comment against the question, Green Day's [Live and let die](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Live_and_Let_Die) (itself just an echo of the title of the Fleming book/Bond film) is unrelated.